# Bad display of list of figures with smfart and smfbook classes

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Using smf classes the list of figures is badly displayed: the name of the figure is written over it's number.

Here's an ECM:

```
\documentclass{smfart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The name of the figure in the list of figures overlaps the number of the figure.

Same problem with the smfbook class.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is inspired by `amsart`, but defines `\l@figure` in a wrong way. I don't have `smfbook` available, I guess the problem and fix are the same.

```
\documentclass{smfart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% fix the wrong definition
\makeatletter
%\def\l@figure{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{}{}} % <--- original
\def\l@figure{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{1.5pc}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit disappointed since I wish to avoid redefining internal commands but it's very kind to have replied so quickly!